# How to pass the variable from my shell script to my chef template recipe?

Tags: chef-infra

I have a shell script whose output is a variable. I am running that shell script through a bash resource in a recipe. I want to be able to access that variable through my chef template. Is there anyway to do this?

```
bash resource:
  "My script which outputs a variable"
EOF
```

I want to output this variable to `template` resource.

Answer (score 0):

Save the output as node attribute if you want to use across Multiple recipes.

```
ruby_block 'get output' do
   block do
      node.default['return_val']=`/tmp/test.sh`
   end
end

template '/tmp/new.sh' do
   source 'test.erb'
   owner 'root'
   group 'root'
   mode '0644'
   variables( lazy {{:config_var => node['return_val']}})
end
```

Kitchen Output:-

```
     * ruby_block[get output] action run
       - execute the ruby block reload client config
     * template[/tmp/new.sh] action create
       - create new file /tmp/new.sh
       - update content in file /tmp/new.sh from none to 2c9c1f
       --- /tmp/new.sh  2016-08-05 13:20:21.678786687 +0000
       +++ /tmp/.chef-new.sh20160805-12338-81wvgw   2016-08-05 13:20:21.678786687 +0000
       @@ -1 +1,2 @@
       +mrigesh
       - change mode from '' to '0644'
       - change owner from '' to 'root'
       - change group from '' to 'root'
       - restore selinux security context
```

Comment: I am using vagrant vms as my nodes

Comment: Please remove this, use of backticks for command execution in Chef is _very_ discouraged because it leads to really bad code.

Comment: Also storing large data in node attibutes is super bad :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to use shell_out instead of back ticks. It just didnt  crossed my mind. :)
Anyhow, for use of node attributes, I have assumed that value needs to be used across multiple recipes. But, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

To refine a bit on what @Mrigesh posted:

Resources don't have an output or return value per se so you need to use a lower-level helper to capture the command output. We offer a nice API called `shell_out!()` to most of the heavy lifting for you. The simplest option would be something like this

```
template '/whatever' do
  # other stuff here
  variables lazy { {config_var: shell_out!('bash /myscript.sh').stdout} }
end
```

This also uses the `lazy{}` helper to make sure the command is run at converge time instead of compile time, which might not be needed depending on your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler method, maybe not so ellegant, but tested.
Within template You put

```
some_value = <%= `some_bash_command`.strip %>
```

I.e. You may want to choose the dynds_iface according to the default route on the machine, to the template you simply put:

```
dyndns_iface = <%= `ip r|awk '/default via/ {print $5}'`.strip %>
```

Back-tick does the job here. It get the shell output of the command. Strip simply removes unnecessary white spaces.